# How to view Google Drive files from connected apps

Tags: google-drive

A free Minecraft hosting offers backups to Google Drive (https://aternos.org/backups/), but they give me no option to download them. I'd still like to have a local copy. I logged into Google Drive from the same account, but it only shows the files I uploaded, not the Aternos backups. Is there any way to get my hands on them? Or maybe Google just hides "my" files from me?

Answer (score 1):

App developers are able to hide the backups they created on Google Drive from the user, create the backup on the user My Drive or on a Team Drive.

If the backup is "hidden", Google show the size of the backup and gives the user the option to delete the backup but not to view or download it

Answer (score 0):

If you click on "Backups" on the left-hand side, is it there?

[image: Drive screenshot]